# Generic mutable and nonmutable parameters for iterator

Tags: parameters, nim-lang, mutability

Here's an iterator that I don't want to copy:

```
iterator testI[T](arr: seq[T]): T =
  # I don't want to copy-paste this body
  # In a real world example it might be much bigger
  for i in 0 ..< arr.len:
    yield arr[i]
```

This works on:

```
for i in testI(@[1,2,3]):
  echo i
```

But not on:

```
var lst = @[1,2,3]
for i in testI(lst):
  i += 1
  echo i
```

I could replace the iterator definition with:

```
iterator testI[T](arr: var seq[T]): var T =
  # I don't want to copy-paste this body
  # In a real world example it might be much bigger
  for i in 0 ..< arr.len:
    yield arr[i]
```

Notice I just added var to the parameter and return. But that makes it no longer work for the non-var case above.

As far as I can tell this problem is equivalent to making the following work:

```
proc foo[A, B](x: A, fn: B) =
  fn(x)

var x = 1
foo(x, proc(x: var int) = x += 1)
foo(1, proc(x: int) = echo x)
assert x != 1
```

For some reason, this doesn't even work:

```
iterator testI[A, B](arr: A): B =
  # I don't want to copy-paste this body
  # In a real world example it might be much bigger
  for i in 0 ..< arr.len:
    yield arr[i]
var lst = @[1,2,3]
for i in testI[var seq[int], var int](lst):
  i += 1
```

In the D programming language there is such this as 'auto ref' parameters that choose to be either reference or value parameters based on whether they are an lvalue or not.

Why is this such a hard problem? I don't want to have to copy-paste the function every time I make an iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually in Nim you'll find two iterators: `items` and `mitems`, one to get the items and not modify them, the other to allow modification. I would try hard to use those procedures before trying to implement something crazy.

But there are times when you have to implement it, so whenever you find yourself in a problem of "code repetition" in Nim that could be solved with Ctrl-C Ctrl-V, you should think in "templates". E.g.

```
template myCycle =
  ## Long and tedious code here.
  for i in 0 ..< arr.len:
    yield arr[i]

iterator testI[T](arr: seq[T]): T =
  echo "Non-var type"
  myCycle

iterator testI[T](arr: var seq[T]): var T =
  echo "Var type"
  myCycle

var lst1 = @[1,2,3]
for i in testI(lst1):
  echo i

let lst2 = @[1,2,3]
for i in testI(lst2):
  echo i
```

When you compile, Nim will copy for you the long code here in `myCycle` and paste it in both of your iterators. Note that you don't have to pass `arr` to the template, as it is not a call but a copy-paste.

---

Nothing better than your last block of code to ilustrate my first point. This is the equivalent code:

```
iterator testI[T](a: var openArray[T]): var T {.inline.} =
  var i = 0
  while i < len(a):
    yield a[i]
    inc(i)

var lst = @[1, 2, 3]
for i in testI(lst):
  i += 1

echo lst
# @[2, 3, 4]
```

This is the code defined in `mitems` for openArrays (already imported in your code via `system`), so the above can be rewritten as:

```
var lst = @[1, 2, 3]
for i in mitems(lst):
  i += 1

echo lst
# @[2, 3, 4]
```